# WSO2 API Manager Custom Routing

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Is there a way to dynamically set the endpoints in WSO2 API Manager to something other than the configured production and sandbox URLs? In my case, I want to route based on an incoming header value; resulting in something like:

```
https://my_dynamically_determined_subdomain.my_static_domain.com
```

I tried doing this with a custom handler class that writes my desired URL to the "To" header, but that doesn't seem to affect the routing.

Is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach seems to be good. You can set "To" header dynamically. But you have to use a [Default Endpoint](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB470/Default+Endpoint), instead of a [HTTP Endpoint](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB470/HTTP+Endpoint). Default Endpoint will send the message to the URL found in "To" header. Please modify your inSequence of the API Configuration (found in $AM_HOME/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/api/your-api.xml) to replace the HTTP endpoint with a Default endpoint, as shown below.

[image: api-manager-default-endpoint]

If you want to do this to all of your APIs, then you can edit velocity_templates.xml so that all the APIs will be published with default endpoints automatically. Please refer [this doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM170/Editing+API+Templates) for more details on this. It is worth to have a look at this [blog post](http://nuwanzone.blogspot.com/2015/03/api-gateways-with-dedicated-back-ends.html) which is discussing a similar pattern what you are trying to do.

Comment: Following the blog example you provided, I created my HTTP Endpoint as simply `https://{uri.var.host}`, and implemented a custom mediator to set the `"uri.var.host"` based on incoming headers.